# how to get data from div tags with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="one">
        welcome
        <div class="two">
            hello world
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            bye world
        </div>
    </div>


    <button onclick="myFunction()">
     Click</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have two divs in div one with class name ,through the function i am able to get tha data of `class="two"` i. hello world.here i want all the data one by one with tha same class name.i want to print all the data with `class="two"` i.e hello world,bye world.plz help me

Comment: `same id` or `same class`? you can use index example `$('.two').eq(0).text() = "hello world"` and `$('.two').eq(1).text() = "bye world"`

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a4ytuntt/1/) check the demo

Comment: upated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a4ytuntt/1/)

Comment: @guradio, your solution is not good. It works, but I think that he has more than two divs with same class and taking in account the dynamic part, your solution is not.

Comment: well looping on the class name would be a good solution i only assume 2 div with same class. @Ionut

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Array#map` to get all the text from each element in the form of array
- Use `Array#join` to concatenate all  items from array with `,` as `glue`

Note: `[].map` is used to make use of `map` method of array over DOMCollection.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('two');
  var mapped = [].map.call(x, function(el) {
    return el.innerHTML; //Or el.textContent;
  });
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = mapped.join(',');
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  welcome
  <div class="two">
    hello world
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    bye world
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `each` function

We can do this by using jQuery's each function. First we push every item in an array then we print it by comma separated.

We push every item in array by using `push` function and then use `join` to show it.

```
<script>
  function myFunction(){
     msg = array();
     $('.className').each(function(){
        msg.push($(this).html());
     });

     $('#demo').html(msg.join(", "));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

class name will get a list of nodes ,so need to loop . Store that all innerhtml in one variable and just add to your element.

```
 function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('two');
            var t="";
            for(var i = 0;i < x.length;i++){
              t += (i == x.length -1) ? x[i].innerHTML : x[i].innerHTML+",";
           }
           document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = t;
        }
```